# Slider next / prev. button

Tags: html, css, button, slider

I´d like to know, if it´s possible to add next and previous buttons to my homepage slider, which is made only with HTML and CSS code (without any Javascript).
If yes - how can i manage it?

https://codepen.io/michal-gambo/pen/zYGrMZo

My website is: autodielytatra.sk.
My code:

```
<div class="content" id="slider">
<figure><a href="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/sk/kategoria/nahradne-diely"><img class="hp-img-print" src="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/files/upload/homepage/images/homepage-1.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" /></a> <a href="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/sk/search?q=plast+%C5%BElt%C3%BD+domie%C5%A1ava%C4%8D"> <img class="hp-img-print" src="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/files/upload/homepage/images/homepage-2.jpg" /></a> <a href="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/sk/kategoria/akciovy-tovar"> <img class="hp-img-print" src="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/files/upload/homepage/images/homepage-3.jpg" /></a> <a href="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/sk/kategoria/nahradne-diely"> <img class="hp-img-print" src="https://www.autodielytatra.sk/files/upload/homepage/images/homepage-1.jpg" /></a></figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google for 'CSS only slider with prev and next buttons' brought up many things, including this:

https://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf

It is very, very difficult to be specific given the information you have provided.

The slider component:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

html, body { background: #333 url("https://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png"); }

.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

      opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
    top: -5px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: You just copy paste the code from the https://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf - I already found this days ago. I just need to know if it is possible to add next prev buttons to slider, that is made with my HTML and CSS code. HTML code is the one I have in the question and the CSS is here:

Comment: #slider { overflow: hidden;}

#slider figure {position: relative; width: 500%; margin: 0; left: 0; animation: 15s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure:hover {
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
 -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
 -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider figure img {float: left; width: 20%;}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {left: 0;}

  20% {left: 0;}

  25% {left: -100%;}

  45% {left: -100%;}

  50% {left: -200%;}

  70% {left: -200%;}

  75% {left: -300%;}

  100% {left: -300%;}
}

Comment: You didn't provide any html or css, just a link to an external website. That's not really how it works. You need to build a codepen and narrow it down to the specific slider element. If you have already found a codepen that solves your problem, why don't you incorporate it into your project?

Comment: because it´s not what I´m looking after. I have a working code - full HTML code is in my question and CSS is in above article. I need the to add next and previous buttons to my code, but I don´t know, if it is possible to implement such option to it - I can put Javascript in it but I don´t know, how to make it working together

Comment: how to add (html, css, javascript) to add next and previous button option???

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you. Sliders with css and javascript is a problem that's already been solved. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: yes that is a little help but it isn´t working as you copy the code and add it to site it shows nothing

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBZWD8B0OF5W

Comment: Uhm, I did something unwise - it´s working thank You very much!